# How to write a program to check if an input equals a standard value

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program that needs to check the resistor inputs to see if they are standard values. I have gotten this far, but I am very confused. Any guidance would help. The main program accepts values from 1-1000 as resistor inputs. These inputs must then be compared to the list of standard values, {10, 12, 15, 18, 22, 27, 33, 39, 47, 56, 68, 82}. Any multiple of these values is considered standard such as 8.2, 82, 820.

```
void checkstdval (float ra, float rb)
{

float stdv[12] = {10, 12, 15, 18, 22, 27, 33, 39, 47, 56, 68, 82};
while(1)
{

    while (ra <10)
    ra *= 10;
    
    while (ra <= 100)
    ra /= 10;
        if ((ra - stdv) < 0.01)
            break;
        else
        {
        
            printf("%.2f is not a standard resistor value\n", ra);
            break;
        }
}

while(1)
{

    while (rb <10)
    rb *= 10;
    while (rb <= 100)
    rb /= 10;
        if ((rb - stdv) < 0.01)
            break;
        else
            {
            
            printf("%.2f is not a standard resistor value\n", rb);
            break;
            
            }
}
```

Comment: The standard resistor values are located in my array........stdv[12] = {10, 12, 15, 18, 22, 27, 33, 39, 47, 56, 68, 82}; I am unable to run the program as it is saying "invalid operands to binary"

Comment: Any number between 1 and 1000 can be entered in the main program, so lets say 1 is entered,,, it must be multiplied by 10 and then compared to the array as it can be any multiple of those standard values (such as 1.2, 12, 120) can all be inputs

Comment: It points to if ((ra - stdv) < 0.01)

Comment: Any idea how to avoid this? My professor told us to do it like this

Comment: There are several problems, but the most obvious one is your comparison here: `if ((ra - stdv) < 0.01)`.  stdv is an array so, you need to compare against a value in the array.  So, something like this: `if ((ra - stdv[i]) < 0.01)`, where `i` is an integer that starts at 0 and is incremented each time through the loop. Then the else test needs to be changed to check if `i` is at the end of the stdv array.

Comment: Iterate over `stdv` with a `for` loop and look at every `stdv[i]`. Does it match? Return true. Does it not match? Try the rest and return false once the entire array is exhausted. Seems like you're pretty close other than that point. Also, it's pretty weird to take 2 inputs and apply the same operation. Why not just have 1 parameter and call the func twice instead of copy-pasting the code? `while (rb <= 100)` seems like you meant `rb > 100`.

Comment: The first loop is fine. The second loop should be `ra >= 100`. Then you need to convert the result to an integer, e.g. `int rv = round(ra)`. Then you need a third loop that compares `rv` to each entry in the `stdv` array. And `stdv` should be an array of `int`.